# Storing image gallery plugin data

Tags: plugins, gallery

I'm making image gallery plugin and I'm not sure what is the best way to store data in WordPress. Plugin can contain multiple gallery instances with some options and each gallery contains images with options. Gallery can be added to site using simple shortcode, something like this: [mygallery id="gallery1"].

So should I use add_option() and store all data in one field or just create two tables for galleries and gallery items?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to store.

- The Settings API uses it's own, well performing, engine behind [Tutorial](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/?all=1)
- You can (miss)use the [Theme modifications API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category%3aTheme_Modification_API) as well
- Or, if it you're talking about adding data to posts, you can use the [Post Meta Storage Engine](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)

*Note: "Post Meta Storage Engine" is no official term. I just used it to surround/house the public API/functions set in a nice name.*

Comment: Thanks, I want to store text data e.g. link to images, effect types, titles...

Comment: @TeddMagwell :) I didn't ask why _type_ of data you want store. It was more about _where_ you want to store it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Gallery Plugin is implemented using Post Types (standard or custom), I would recommend using Attachment post custom metadata.

However, I would **strongly** recommend that you look into hooking into WordPress' existing gallery/media-management implementation, rather than re-inventing the gallery wheel.

Comment: Really? Media Management is pretty crappy. You're right in general, but it's really ... crappy.

Comment: Thus, the suggestion to *filter* it, to make it *better*. ;) Make the Gallery a Custom Post Type, and filter the Media Manager, to allow for inclusion of taxonomies and custom metadata. Best of all worlds.

Comment: Without thinking about it: Sounds good. And here goes the upvote. Btw: Join us in chat :)

Comment: Unfortunately, chat is... finicky for me :)